# Extract data from Get requests in python FLASK

Tags: rest

I have a front on which forms for data entry, I enter data there and they go to the backend, but I need to intercept them and write them to the database. I have a script that writes data to a database, but I don't understand how to intercept the data. I am using the Flask framework. Help me please!

```
@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return "<html><head></head><body>A RESTful API in Flask using.</a>.</body></html>"

@app.route('/api/v1/reports/', methods='GET'):
```

Comment: HTTP GET is used for retrieving data. If you want to send data use HTTP POST/PUT/PATCH. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: I understand. I need to get the data that is sent from the frontend to the backend and write it to the database.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Create new HTTP Method (POST) for this endpoint.
import this `from flask import request, jsonify`
and inside function 
`data = jsonify(request.json)`